# java pintar pirámide de asteriscos

Tags: java

dibujaPiramide1: recibe un entero, n, como parámetro de entrada y dibuja una
pirámide cuya última fila tendrá n carácteres: (no devuelve nada)

Lo que consigo hacer es que me devuelva tantas lineas como N pero no tantos caracteres en la ultima linea.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
public void dibujaPiramide1(int num) {
        for(int altura = 1; altura<=num; altura++){
            //Espacios en blanco
            for(int blancos = 1; blancos<=num-altura; blancos++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Asteriscos
        for(int asteriscos=1; asteriscos<=(altura*2)-1; asteriscos++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solamente te faltó mostrar, al final del `for` externo, la variable `asteriscos`. Pero hay un pequeño problema: como `asteriscos` es **local** al `for` interno, o sea es una variable propia de ese `for`, cuando la querés usar fuera de su ámbito (llaves `{}`) no es posible ya que no se reconoce. Por lo tanto hay que declararla por fuera, como una variable global del método `dibujaPiramide1`. Así:

```
public void dibujaPiramide1(int num) {
    int asteriscos =0;//declaración de variable global de este método. Es obligatorio inicializarla, de lo contrario no compila.
    for(int altura = 1; altura <= num; altura++){
        //Espacios en blanco
        for(int blancos = 1; blancos <= num-altura; blancos++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        //Asteriscos
        for(asteriscos =1 ;asteriscos <= (altura*2)-1; asteriscos++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");//salto de linea
    }
    asteriscos--;//decrementamos unidad por que incrementa una más en la última iteración
    System.out.println("Cantidad de caracteres en la base de la pirámide: "+asteriscos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no es correcto, ya que al final pinta n*2-1 en la base de la pirámide, lo que te están pidiendo es que pintes n asteriscos en la base, luego tu código debería ser:

```
public static void dibujaPiramide1(int num) {
    int asteriscos=1;


    for(int j = 1; j<=num; j++){
        //Espacios en blanco
        for(int blancos = 1; blancos<=num-j; blancos++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Asteriscos
        for(int i=1; i<=asteriscos; i++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        asteriscos++;
    }
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que la altura es del número que le metas y que por cada asterisco debes meter un espacio en blanco en medio. Pruébalo y mira el resultado, a ver si es el que esperas. Como no has puesto un ejemplo de una pirámide ya dibujada con asteriscos, no estoy seguro de que sea el resultado esperado Pero creo que es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Si que es lo que pido, muchas gracias.